# Python iterator unexpected behavior while modifying its list inside a for-in loop

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

The main rule is: do not modify a list while iterating over it, but...

Given the following code to remove a specific element in a python list (but intentionally written as a loop):

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

for i in mylist:
    if i == 'c':
        mylist.remove(i)

print(mylist)

>> ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

How is that the iterator does not get lost while iterating if the list is being modified inside the loop? I expected this to yield an error or an inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List iterators (other iterators may behave differently) work by remembering what index they are currently at, and when you call next it checks to see if the index is in range, and if so, gets an item and then updates the index. Your code reaches index 2, removes `'c'`, then goes to index 3, which is now the `'e'` entry and continues on, skipping the `'d'` entry completely. If you add a print statement in the for loop, you'll see the behaviour.

You can have a look at the C source code for list objects at:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c

Look for "listiter_next" to see the implementation.

It checks if the current index is less than the length of the list:

```
if (it->it_index < PyList_GET_SIZE(seq))
```

and if it is, gets the item and increments the index:

```
item = PyList_GET_ITEM(seq, it->it_index);
++it->it_index;
```